# Order a list but respect integer ordering (natural sort order)

Tags: code-golf

Given a list of *n* strings, return a list of that strings in ascending order. However, be aware, that in this case we want integer comparison for all numbers appearing in the strings, meaning that "12" > "3".

Example cases:

```
{"abc123", "abc6", "abc47", "abd49"} -> {"abc6", "abc47", "abc123", "abd49"}
{"foo0", "bar12", "foobar12", "foo"} -> { "bar12", "foo", "foo0", "foobar12"}
{"Bond007", "Bond07", "Bond7", "Bond12"} -> {"Bond007", "Bond07", "Bond7", "Bond12"}
{"one1", "one11two23", "one1two2", "one1two3", "1"} -> {"1", "one1", "one1two2", "one1two3", "one11two23"}
```

You can expect to only find *[a-zA-Z0-9]+* in each string.
This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so shortest code in bytes wins. 
[Standard Loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) are forbidden.

Update:
- Sorting is case insensitive
- The ascending order is *integers* < "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
- Every sequence of integers as in the aforementioned order should be interpreted as one integer, meaning "421" represents 421, not 4, 2 and 1 and thus is smaller than "1341", as 421 < 1341

-Treat numbers with leadings zeroes as though they were decimals meaning "001" -> "0.01" so "001" < "01" < "1"

Thanks for Adám for pointing out, that this is called natural sort order.

Comment: So, you mean order it by consecutive integers inside the strings?  Or you could mean order it by all integers inside the string?

Comment: How funny. I was planning on posting this challenge.

Comment: Unfortunately, there are a lot specifications missing here.

Comment: Yes. Unclear rules. foo < foo0 but Bond007 < Bond7. I first thought (foo):(foo)(0) => (Bond)(007) (Bond)(7). Is uppercase/lowercase of any significance?

Comment: (VTC as unclear because of ^)

Comment: This is called [natural sort order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_sort_order).

Comment: To prevent the challenge being unclear you should `1` provide a rigorous mathematical definition, `2` give a reference implementation and `3` (optional, but recommended) sandbox the challenge.

Comment: All your test cases do not indicate case-sensitivity or not. I would advise against making this rule as you may invalidate existing answers, and it doesn't really add to the challenge.

Comment: You have not specified how to sort `01` vs `1` and your examples do not indicate it either as the only relevant example is the "bond" one and the output has the same order as the input. Does the longer come first, or are they considered the same and just stay in input order?

Comment: So by the decimals rule, `012` < `03` < `2` ?

Comment: @Adám It's also their fault to answer an unclear challenge.

Comment: Also, it's still unclear what to do about `01` vs. `010`.

Comment: The decimals' rule doesn't make any sense. I think what you want is that otherwise identical numbers, but where some have leading zeros, should sort by length, longest first, right?

Comment: Since the case insensitivity leads to ties you have to specify if the sort has to be stable or not. I suggest not since otherwise you force people whose language sort is unstable to implement their own sort

Comment: Adding to what @TonHospel said: Alternatively, you can specify a secondary sort order, e.g. that when tie-breaking, lowercase comes before uppercase. But again, I think you're better off making it case sensitive and just go by ASCII order.

Comment: This is a nice challenge I'd like to do but the spec is still incomplete. So could you please update your question ? The only things you still need to do is to specify how ties in the sorting are to be handled and fix the rule for leading zeros (presumably saying that more leading zeros sort before less leading zeros instead of trying to get to this using fractions).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 7 bytes

```
ΣDþïs)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//3GKXw/sOry/WrP3/P1opPy/VUElHAUwblpTnGxnDeCAOEhssbqgUCwA)

## Explanation

```
ΣDþïs)}  Full Program
Σ     }  Sort by result of key: a
 D       a, a
  þ      digits_only(a), a
   ï     int(digits_only(a)), a
    s    a, int(digits_only(a))
     )   [a, int(digits_only(a))]
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 68 bytes

```python
lambda l:sorted(l,key=lambda x:int(re.sub("\D","",x)or 0))
import re
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY9BCoMwEEX3OcWQlYFQjJWWCm5Kb6EutEYaGhOJKdXT2yRacTPz5vP/MDPM9qVVsnR5uci6b9oaZDZqY3kbSfrmc76pUyaUjQw/jZ8mwuUDU4zpRLSBmBAk@sFlwPBFihFyKBBAgevmyZIzpuDpsvX0ukKb3nBFg6/TOvZiUxuWeHDCkf@@u1ZtHId8wJ12cJHNqxVnXvWd2a9e7/CTHw4c9GDFFaoQ6txLUoBQro6Z2zUY/3kXSUHI8gM)

I used something like this to sort PDF files recently!

*my entry originally didn't work but [Neil](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/67929/neil) fixed it (thanks!)*

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 6](https://perl6.org),  <s>32 31</s>  30 bytes

```perl6
*.sort(*.comb(/\d+|\D+/)».&val)
```

[Test it](https://tio.run/##jY/PToNAEMbv@xQTDs1uaSnUBmM3GDR682g89QLsNCFSdsOfKlGfzJsvhruAlCbGeJpvv/nNtzMKi8xv6xLh6DsJJ@TQwCyRAiFo504pi4rOnUQeYrraCft9d2ev2NenMztGGWu5ocMKywoCyNIcS926f7p54MQkPuoGJyqLcrA7ipO9LIaB5TXQ7TM2NExzVVdsAVudWSMN8VVhUqFgwOCNAKTlUiCqrAGz14kfwYl0lL6Hk4@WWlGceOsLawFG@UPdXPZCbK4sBoHe4bfuabDjCLX2UrrGiaPCWxuhjakews6BobhnvEm7lblw3e6zTo5qFAbs1/sfq0Nljp6xTPWqF9mfYF7mMdGd7/3kjzN/0ZNM9g0)

```perl6
*.sort(*.comb(/\d+|\D/)».&val)
```

[Test it](https://tio.run/##jY/PToNAEMbv@xQTDs1u/1CoDcZuMGj05tF46oWy04RI2Q0sVaI@mTdfDHcBKU2M8TTffvObb2cUFlnQVCXCMXATTsihhkkiBULYTN1SFppO3UQednS5FbP37d2SfX26k2OcsYZbONJYagghS3MsTev@6eaBExv4aBqcqCzOYdZSnOxl0Q8sroFunrGmUZqrSrM5bExmhTTCV4WJRsGAwRsBSMuFQFRZDXatEz@AI@kqcw4nHw114l3iry6cOVgV9HV92QmxvnIYhGaH37qnwZYj1NlL6VlnFxf@ygpjjHUfdg70xTvjbdqtzIXntZ@1clCDsGC33v9YEypz9K1lq69fZHeCfdnHSLe@/5M/zPxFjzLZNw)

```perl6
*.sort(*.comb(/\d+|./)».&val)
```

[Test it](https://tio.run/##jY/LTsMwEEX3/opRFpXdh5uUKohaQQGJHUvEik0eUykija3EKUTAl7Hjx4KdhDSVEGI113fOXM8oLHO/rSuEo88TQcihgVkiU4SgnfNKlprOeSIPMV0/pYt3vmZfn3x2jHLWCsuGGisNAeRZgZVp3T3e3Ati8x5MQxCVRwUsOkqQvSyHgdU10N0zNjTMClVrtoSdyayRhviqMNGYMmDwRgCyapUiqrwBu9WJH8GJ5MpcI8hHS50oTrzNhbMEq/yhbi97kW6vHAaB2eG37mmw4wh19lK61omj0ttYYYypHsLOgaG4Z7xNu5VF6rrdZ50c1Sgs2K/3P9aEygI9a9nq6RfZn2Bf9jHRne/95I8zf9GTTPYN)

### Expanded:

```perl6
*\                         # WhateverCode lambda (this is the parameter)

.sort(                     # sort by doing the following to each string

  *.comb( / \d+ | . / )\ # split the string into consecutive digits or a character

  ».&val                   # convert each to a Numeric if possible

)
```

Note:

```perl6
"Bond007".comb(/\d+|\D+/)».&val
# results in
("Bond", IntStr.new(7, "007"))

# and

"Bond007".comb(/\d+|./)».&val
# results in
("B", "o", "n", "d", IntStr.new(7, "007"))
```

Answer (score 2):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/) 17.0 (currently in alpha), 31 [bytes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9429/43319)<sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)</sup>

Anonymous tacit prefix function taking a list of strings as argument.

```apl
⊂⊃¨⍨∘⍋({0::⍵⋄⍎⍵}¨⊢⊂⍨1,2≠/∊∘⎕D)¨
```

As version 17.0 isn't on TIO yet, here is a test session transcript:

```apl
      f←⊂⊃¨⍨∘⍋({0::⍵⋄⍎⍵}¨⊢⊂⍨1,2≠/∊∘⎕D)¨
      ⎕JSON f ⎕JSON '["abc123", "abc6", "abc47", "abd49"]'
["abc6","abc47","abc123","abd49"]
      ⎕JSON f ⎕JSON '["foo0", "bar12", "foobar12", "foo"]'
["bar12","foo","foo0","foobar12"]
      ⎕JSON f ⎕JSON '["Bond007", "Bond07", "Bond7", "Bond12"]'
["Bond007","Bond07","Bond7","Bond12"]
      ⎕JSON f ⎕JSON '["one1", "one11two23", "one1two2", "one1two3", "1"]'
["1","one1","one1two2","one1two3","one11two23"]
```

---

`⊂` from the entire argument…

`⊃¨⍨` pick each of the indices…

`∘` that are…

`⍋` the ascending grade (indices which would place in ascending order) of…

`(`…`)¨` the following tacit function applied to each of the strings:

`∊∘⎕D` Boolean mask for the characters which are members of the set of **D**igits

`2≠/` pairwise inequality of that (i.e. indicate beginnings of letter runs and digit runs)

`1,` prepend 1 to mark the first character as beginning a run

`⊢⊂⍨` use that to partition (beginning partitions at 1s) the string

`{`…`}¨` apply the following anonymous lambda to each partition:

`0::` if any error happens, then:
   `⍵` return the argument as-is

`⋄` try to:
   `⍎⍵` evaluate the argument

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 125 bytes

```python
lambda a:[y for _,y in sorted([([i%2and int(e)or e for i,e in enumerate(re.findall("(\D+|\d+)",s))],s)for s in a])]
import re
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PYzBCgIhFEX3fcVDCJSRmKZFELSJ/kIlXvgkYUYHxxYD/btpwWwuh8u5d17zK4ZTcVddRpyeFgEvagUXEzzkCj7AElMmyxVXfj9gsLXLnEQV6Kd5SU2j8J4oYSae6OB8sDiOnHF97z7adoLJRQhTo02WNkAjzM5Pc72HRGVO7ddxxW4x2L4/Mwl/3GiD48CMEOUL)

Comment: Seems to [ignore zeros](https://tio.run/##PYzLCsIwEEX3fkUICBNaSq0LQehG/Is0i5FMMNI8SOJC8N9jg9Dd4d7DiZ/yDP5czbzUFd1DI8Or5Hx4BevBYYRcUp@FMCGxzKxnOaRCGqS0xwm93qYCJLaXWHNsT80i/3aUsBAkGoz1GtcVOCz37rvoTvCWVHsTlVAH6@KWZolqTC1qQPJb8HocL7xnf9xph9PElRD1Bw).

Comment: @JonathanFrech Thanks, fixed for -11 bytes

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <strike>107</strike> 106 bytes

```python
import re
lambda a:sorted(a,key=lambda x:[n.isdigit()and n.zfill(9)or n for n in re.findall('\d+|\D+',x)])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jVHRboMgFH3nK276UkiJ0bbZUhNflv2F9QELbGQWDJJMl/27A1zVLssyH7jnnnM4xJx2cK9GH8ZRXVtjHViBZNGwa80ZsLzzlOCY0Tcx3Ng@L3WiOq5elMOEaQ46@ZCqafCJGAsaZDyV9lmJVJozL9ntme8@z8@7Le1JRUYuJDjROdzTgeQI/NdapR2WuCfkxw5FAQNB6MI60UEBZdRxuWH1JdsfNhQCeviex8cJ8ONpU1Eof9OWa9FF6C1RGpMGoWY22wfgiTWeEu@YaaR35lXik9E8TeO7Ec5oBsEfUv/nXJKNFllQwszcu5l@KWxhWeHIZ9Mj842/vKvEiqAKhUZ9UaHT2EG@dDd@AQ)

Abused the fact that Python compares two lists lexicographically. Unfortunately `re.split(r'\b',x)` does not work.

Comment: `r'...` -> `'...`.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that works.

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 92 bytes

```python
lambda q:map(lambda a:a[1],sorted(map(lambda a:[int(re.sub("\D","",a)or 0),a],q)))
import re
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY/BCoMwEETv@YolpwRCMVZaKngp/QvNYa1KA5potJR@vU3USnvJvpnMhGz/nh7WxHOTFXOLXVkhDGmHPdsEpphLJUbrprpifxe5NhNz9WF8lowWNyooFcitg4gLVGLgnBPd9b4Jrp5bPUIGOQHIKZZ3GR@pgECnbSbnFarkQpVYco21UTBLdDIO4I1f/uau1lRRtPQX3GkHX9my1tQyuGHK6WXXfwQVxA8vvqSKKEIav1WrQRt/jql/p3dh@Ya1mvP5Aw)

Answer (score 1):

## [PHP 7](http://php.net/docs.php), 17 bytes

```
<?php natsort()?>
```

[natsort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.natsort.php) — *"Sort an array using a 'natural order' algorithm"*